# Which C. elegans would be appropriate for general study?

Tags: reproduction, growth

Would wild type N2 be best or Dyp-11? I know they're different, but I just want to observe the worms to see life stages, movement, etc. Dyp-11 seems like it would be easy to see but N2 is the wild type so I need help making an appropriate decision.

Comment: What do you want to see? Just the worms?

Comment: What question do you want to answer? The "appropriate" decision will depend on what exactly you want to investigate. What conclusions will you want to draw from your research?

Comment: Yes, all I want to see is the worms themselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that that dpy-11-mutants (that's what you likely meant) are not very representative neither from the morphological nor from the behavioral points of view, because they have anomalies in body shape (dumpy appearance) and male tail morphology (see in [WormBase](http://www.wormbase.org/species/c_elegans/gene/WBGene00001073?from=http://www.wormbase.org/db/gene/gene?name=dpy-11#0-9e-3) and in [Ko and Chow](http://dev.biologists.org/content/129/5/1185.full.html)).

For a general purpose the wild-type should be best.